# Loading a texture from file post DX11.1?

Tags: directx, textures, directx-11, texture2d, sharpdx

In 11.1 and later Microsoft removed a lot of helpers for loading textures (fromfile, fromstream etc).

I'm trying to port my code over to 11.2 and everything works fine except for this line :

```
var texture = Texture2D.FromFile<Texture2D>(device, @"C:\Texture.png");
```

Now all i could find was guidance telling me to use WIC instead but i can't seem to find anything providing me with a Texture2D that is nearly as versatile (all the samples i found require passing in the pixel format among other things).

I'm looking for a solution that would let me load files (without knowing their format or layout before hand) and get a Texture2D out of it just like FromFile allowed. Is there anything like that or even close? I'm assuming there has to be "something" as they wouldn't just deprecate such a feature if it wasn't superfluous.

Any help is most appreciated.

Edit : I'd like to avoid using the SharpDX.Toolkit too, i'm looking for a raw DirectX / WIC etc solution as i don't want to add a dependency on the Toolkit. I'm however perfectly fine on adding any .net Framework 4.0 or 4.5 assembly as a dependency.

Comment: What programming language do you use? Is it VB.net?

Comment: Not sure why this would matter but i'm using C#

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no easy solution apart from writing the whole WIC interop yourself. Even if you don't want to use the Toolkit, the source code is available and the class [WicHelper.cs](https://github.com/sharpdx/Toolkit/blob/master/Source/Toolkit/SharpDX.Toolkit.Graphics/WICHelper.cs) responsible for decoding images is fairly easy to adapt.

If you want a very simple solution that doesn't handle all WIC cases (format mappings...etc.), you can have a look at [TextureLoader.cs](https://github.com/sharpdx/SharpDX-Samples/blob/master/StoreApp/OldSamplesToBeBackPorted/CommonDX/TextureLoader.cs).

Comment: Looks like what i need, what kind of formats will this handle by default? Any Format32bppPRGBA or only bitmap? (Will this automagically load png gif jpeg etc?). Also is it possible to load arbitrary data with WIC or just standard formats? (If i have an array of 128 bit per pixel data, no headers no nothing in memory, can i convert this to a texture2D without going through a standard format?)

Comment: Only Format32bppPRGBA and file format supported by WIC. To load arbitrary raw data, initialize the texture directly with the data at creation time.

Answer (score 1):

Provided you have both a `Texture2D` and a WPF `BitmapImage` lying around, something like this will help:

```
  var map = device.ImmediateContext.MapSubresource(texture, 0, MapMode.WriteDiscard, MapFlags.None);
  bitmap.CopyPixels(Int32Rect.Empty, map.DataPointer, bitmap.PixelWidth * bitmap.PixelHeight * 4, bitmap.PixelWidth * 4);
  device.ImmediateContext.UnmapSubresource(source, 0);
```

The function you mention was probably something fairly similar under the hood.

If you're not sure about the bitmap being Bgra, you have to convert it first.